# telebot, python: How to pause 'for' cycle with an inline keyboard in it untill a button is pressed by user?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, telegram-bot

I have a voting bot that uploads photos to use pack by pack (one pack contains certain amount of images) with double for loop (one for going through packs, or 'entries', and one for uploading images) and then presents inline keyboard with photo's numbers.

Ideally I want it to pause every time a keyboard is presented untill a button is pressed. But now it just goes through all the packs and all the keyboards without any pause.

The raw code of voting presentation is (it's called from another function under telebot message handler):

```
def start_vote(message):
    entries = os.listdir('entries/')
    for entry in entries:
        entry_num = entries.index(entry) + 1
        bot.reply_to(message, f"Pack {entry_num}")
        images = os.listdir('entries/' + entry + '/')
        items = []
        for image in images:
            image_num = images.index(image) + 1
            bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id,
                            open('entries/' + entry + '/' + image, 'rb'),
                            image_num,
                            parse_mode = "HTML")
            items.append(types.InlineKeyboardButton(image_num, callback_data = f'{entry_num}_{image_num}'))
            
        voting_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        for item in items:
            voting_markup.add(item)
   
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Choose an image:', reply_markup = voting_markup)
        time.sleep(5)
```

And then there's a separate callback response function when the button is pressed:

```
def callback_inline(call):
    pack_num = call.data.split('_')[0]
    image_num = call.data.split('_')[1]
    db_add_vote(call.from_user.id, pack_num, image_num)
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id = call.message.chat.id, message_id = call.message.message_id, text = f"You've chosen image num {image_num}", reply_markup = None)
```

I'm not sure if it's possible through pyTeleBot api or with some other trick.

The 'next step' handler seems to only work with messages and not callback data and it's important for me to have the keyboard inline, next to the message it's refering to. Sure enough I can just do separate voting functions for each pack but still it seems like I'm missing something important.